# How to restrict the date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need a small validation in Sql for `from date` and `to date` columns i have.
suppose I have given `01/08/2014` and `30/08/2014`
Again the front end user should not give this date period.
I can restrict by using below validation like,

```
select  DocEntry from  [@PR_OTIMESHEET] where U_frmdate >='20140801' and U_todate <='20140830'
```

but user may be give like 
from `date = 15/08/2014` and to `date = 30/08/2014`.

In this case above query is become false.
between `01/08/2014` and `30/08/2014` should not give again .
May I know how can I restrict the users ?

Comment: are you referring a restriction on the input date format or range?

Answer (score 0):

The way to query based on a date tends to change based on your database.

For Microsoft SQL Server you need to use CONVERT

Example:

```
CONVERT(datetime, '20140801', 112)
```

The 112 is a specified date format. See other date formats here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx

so your example should be:

```
select  DocEntry from  [@PR_OTIMESHEET] where U_frmdate >= CONVERT(datetime, '20140801', 112) and U_todate <= CONVERT(datetime, '20140801', 112)
```

NOTE: Your select range doesn't make any sense as the dates are the same!! So this will only return stuff where the date is exactly 2014-08-01 00:00:00

Comment: hi CathlMF Thanks for your reply. Above one is not useful to me.

Comment: Without converting also above what i written is working fine. but my question is if he gives the range . second time the between value also he should not give.

Comment: suppor 100 to 200 i given first time second time 150 to 200 the sql should not accept bcz 150 is comes under 100 to 200 am i correct. are anything is wrong.